# Dynamic creation of rows into columns (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 tables. Table user stores information of users like below.

```
**user_id      user_name**
1            naveen
2            richard
3            reddy
```

Another table User_activity. stores the details of user Plan.

```
**user_id      Activity   date**
1            holiday   1-aug-2016
2            working   1-aug-2016
3            training  1-aug-2016
1            working   2-aug-2016
2            working   2-aug-2016
3            working   2-aug-2016
```

Now I need to create a report in below format. please help me to write a query for the same.

```
**Date         naveen        Richard     reddy**
1-aug-2016   holiday       working     training
2-aug-2016   working       working     working
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what if you have more than 3 users? Do you expect to build a query with a variable number of columns?

Comment: Just working through pivot function. But as u told I am not able to create if no of users are more than 3. Looking for the best solution.

Comment: You can not build a plain SQL returning a result with a variable number of columns. You can build a dynamic SQL and then run it, this will give a variable number of columns, but how to handle that result? Other way, you can build  a result with a single column containing the concatenation of the values, with some separator

Answer (score 0):

No way to do that. (except for PIVOT_XML).

Long story short:
when you execute the query Oracle will send you description of columns and their data types. Even before it actually touches any data.

Oracle uses producer-consumer principle, so data are sent to client as they are evaluated - result set is not buffered on server side.

So your request goes against this principle. If number of columns was dependent on data content, Oracle would have to change the result set parameters on the fly - which is not possible.

PIVOT_XML is an exception, because it generates only one CLOB column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something slightly different, building your output with a single column containing the concatenation of data.
Assuming that every user has exactly an activity for each day, you can try something like that:

```
with users(user_id, user_name) as
(
    select 1, 'naveen' from dual union all
    select 2, 'richard' from dual union all
    select 3, 'reddy' from dual
),
user_activity( user_id, Activity, activity_date) as
(
    select 1, 'holiday'  , date '2016-08-01' from dual union all
    select 2, 'working'  , date '2016-08-01' from dual union all
    select 3, 'training' , date '2016-08-01' from dual union all
    select 1, 'working'  , date '2016-08-02' from dual union all
    select 2, 'working'  , date '2016-08-02' from dual union all
    select 3, 'working'  , date '2016-08-02' from dual
)
select rpad('Date', 16, ' ') || ',' || listagg(rpad(user_name, 16, ' '), ',') within group (order by user_id)
from users
union all
select rpad(to_char(activity_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),16, ' ') || ',' || listagg(rpad(activity, 16, ' '), ',') within group (order by user_id)
from users 
      inner join user_activity using(user_id)
group by activity_date
```

The result:

```
RPAD('DATE',16,'')||','||LISTAGG(RPAD(USER_NAME,16,''),',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYUS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date            ,naveen          ,richard         ,reddy
2016-08-01      ,holiday         ,working         ,training
2016-08-02      ,working         ,working         ,working
```

If I add a fourth man:

```
RPAD('DATE',16,'')||','||LISTAGG(RPAD(USER_NAME,16,''),',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYUSER_ID)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date            ,naveen          ,richard         ,reddy           ,Fourth Man
2016-08-01      ,holiday         ,working         ,training        ,training
2016-08-02      ,working         ,working         ,working         ,working
```